# Prove that $W \cup S^1$ is connected in the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness

I want to solve the following question:

> Prove that the union of $W$ and the unit circle $S^1$ is connected in the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R^2}$ where $W=\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R^2} | x=(1-e^{-t})cost, y=(1-e^{-t})sint, t \geq0\}$

I know that a connected topological space, $X$ is *connected* if it does **not** split into open disjoint non-empty subsets.

Also, for a space $(Y, \tau)$ the *subspace topology* on $X \subset Y$ is $\tau|_X=\{U \cap X : U \in \tau\}$.

How can the union be connected, since you are taking the union of non-empty subsets?

Comment: 'How can the union be connected, since you are taking the union of non-empty subsets?'

$(0,2) \cup (1,3)=(0,3)$ which is connected. Don't forget the disjoint part of the definition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$W$ is connected (since it is a path). Note that $\overline{W}$ is connected, since it is the closure of a connected set. But $\overline{W}=W \cup S^1$.

Comment: How is $(1,0)$ in $W$? I can only see that it should be an accumulation point of $W$. Isn't $|(1-e^{-t}) cos t| \leq |1-e^{-t}| < 1$ for $t\geq 0$?

Comment: @sqtrat Brain malfunctioning and assuming that $e^0=0$.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo thanks. Can you elaborate as to why the closure is this union? Does it have something to do with limit points?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Thank you for the reply. I was wondering how you knew that $\bar{W}=W\cup S^1$

Comment: @thinker If you draw a figure, you can see that $W$ is spiralling towards $S^1$. If you want to prove it, just prove the following things: - First, any point in the circle is a limit point (this can be done by using the fact that $e^{-t} \to 0$ and the spiral keeps doing rotations). Secondly, any point out of the unit disk is not a limit point (this is obvious). Third, any point inside the unit disk which is not in the path is not a limit point. This follows from the fact that the spiral keeps going "outwards". Hence, it suffices to separate the point from a compact part of the path.

Comment: Formally if $A$ is connected and $A\subseteq B\subseteq\overline{A}$ then $B$ is connected, so it is enough to prove that $W\cup S^1\subseteq\overline{W}$, i.e. that $S^1\subseteq\overline{W}$ (even if it is indeed the case that equality holds $W\cup S^1=\overline{W}$). Note that every $(x,y)\in S^1$ is of the form $(x,y)=(\cos(t_0),\sin(t_0))$ for a suitable $t_0\in[0,2\pi)$. Then use that $\lim_{n\to\infty} ((1-e^{-(t_0+2\pi n)})\cos(t_0), (1-e^{-(t_0+2\pi n)})\sin(t_0))=(\cos(t_0),\sin(t_0))=(x,y)\in\overline{W}$. Since $(x,y)\in S^1$ was arbitrary, this proves $S^1\subseteq\overline{W}$